# Add picture into the Microsoft Outlook body

Tags: vb.net, outlook

Method 1: Following four steps explains how to add picture into Microsoft Outlook mail.

1- Copy any picture from your computer.

2- Open Microsoft Outlook.

3- Open new mail screen.

4- Paste that picture into the mail screen.

Method 2: Following codes show how to add picture into Microsoft Outlook mail via code.

```
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
```

.

```
 "< img src='c:\folder\filename.jpg'>"
```

The difference between these two methods is that the second method needs internet connection / computer connection in order to being viewed that picture from recipient side.

How to combine these two methods that picture should be viewed even internet connection / computer connection is not available.

So, I am looking for a vb.net / html code which copies picture from internet / computer and paste into the outlook body.

Please dont advice adding picture with attachment method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the image through its cid: `<img src="cid:xyz">` where "xyz" is the value of the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property set on the attachment.

where `xyz` is the value of the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property.

Look at an existing message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am it author - click IMessage button, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab).

```
attachment = MailItem.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "xyz")
MailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test image <img src=""cid:xyz""></body></html>"
```